# Spring Boot file transformer implementation in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a standalone java application that transforms several file formats one to another.

So it works over the Main.java like

```
new DocxToHtmlConverter().docxToHtml("File.docx",".File.html");
```

I want to implement a spring boot application that does the same thing through `localhost` url.

I will also implement a selection algorithm on top of this. For example an `if` clauses to execute the wanted algorithm based on the input string extentions.(can be used endsWith(".docx") etc.

Basically, If i write like `localhost:8080/{inputFile,outputFile}` and then based on the file extension, related class will be chosen and i should be able to download the resulted file. In this case it is `html`.

I never used Spring before, so forgive me for my ignorence. I dont even know if this kind of operations are valid with Spring. Thats why I am asking.

What would be the best approach to go with? any kind of helpful links or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: You could try setting up springboot following the guide here https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ , and once you're ready, you can simply set up your own POST method and implement the logic behind it :) . If you still need more infos, feel free to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do it. This response describes one solution that lets you keep your library spring agnostic.

You have to create a configuration class that will define a bean with your implementation. You will be able to directly inject this bean into any bean in your spring project

```java
@Configuration
public class DocxToHtmlConverterConfig{
  @Bean
  public DocxToHtmlConverter docxToHtmlConverter(){
    return new DocxToHtmlConverter();
  }
}
```

This configuration class will create a bean with `DocxToHtmlConverter` implementation that you can autowayer in any component of your application as follows

```java
@RestController //or @Controller or @{any annotation that declares a component}
public class MyService{
  @Autowired
  DocxToHtmlConverter docxToHtmlConverter;

  public void convertFile(){
    docxToHtmlConverter.docxToHtml("File.docx",".File.html");
  }   
}
```

Comment: yes, I actually managed it. Surprisingly it was very easy to do. I was just lost in all of these tutorials and examples. I still need to understand all the components deeply. It works and it is fine. But i dont know why it works and how it works. Anyways, i will accept your answer.